# How to redirect process output by using C++ ACE library

Tags: ace

I need to write c++ code that uses the ACE library to create a process by building a string of its command line and redirect its output to a text file. I tried  to use ACE_Process and ACE_Process_option classes. I set ACE_Process_option.command_line by using the following format, with the redirect operator: "    >    ". Unfortunately, it didn't work: the string that I build (the value of ACE_Process_option.command_line field) activates the process and redirect it to a text file when I write it in the cmd (the command line console), but it doesn't work when I try to use it from the code. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Check chapter 10 of the [ACE Programmers Guide](http://www.remedy.nl/opensource/ace.html). The example code of this section is available as part of the ACE distribution under `examples/APG/Processes`, see the `Manager::setStdHandles` operation as part of the `Spawn.cpp` example

Comment: Thank you very much Johnny :-). It seems to be exactly what I've been looking for. I'll check it